# Joda DateTime set noon today

Tags: jodatime

I have 2 DateTime objects. The first i set to midnight just gone, the second i want to set to 12 hours later (noon today).

Both objects are set to midnight just gone. Why is this? I've specified 12 hrs later as a long eg 43300000.

thanks in advance

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y H:mm");
        DateTime lastNightMidnight = new DateTime().toDateMidnight().toDateTime();
        String formattedLastNightMidnight = fmt.print(lastNightMidnight);
        textViewAwayFrom.setText(formattedLastNightMidnight);

        DateTime todayNoon = new DateTime().toDateMidnight().plus(43300000L).toDateTime();
        String formattedTodayNoon = fmt.print(todayNoon);
        textViewAwayTo.setText(formattedTodayNoon);

        Log.e(TAG, "lastNightMidnight = " + lastNightMidnight + " todayNoon = " + todayNoon);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should not use `DateMidnight` because it is deprecated.
2. You should also not use `plusHours(12)` because you don't want to do arithmetic but just set the hour of day.

Best way is (see [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withHourOfDay%28int%29)):

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime noon = dt.withHourOfDay(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime todayNoon = new DateTime().toDateMidnight().toDateTime().plusHours(12);
```